# Visual studio code Terminal is not opening giving error code

Tags: visual-studio, terminal

the terminal process terminated with exit code: 127 I keep gettin this every time I try to open the terminal in Visual studio code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Have you tried checking your path?
2. I have also seen something like this when tasks.json was all messed up.
3. Go through your settings at File-> Preferences-> Settings-> Features-> Terminal and see if anything looks wonky.

You will need to post your environment path and/or tasks.json if you don't discover the issue yourself to help you troubleshoot further.